# How to generate a sequential account number?

Tags: java

I am making a bank account program and for my constructor I want it to add the customers name(which it does) and I also want it to automatically generate an account number for each customer added starting from 1 to n customers(which it does NOT do...), if I have 3 names it prints the num 3 for each of their accNum when I add these names to an ArrayList in my "BankDataBase" class.

```
public class Customer
{
private final String fname;
private final String lname;


Customer(String fn, String ln)
{
    fname = fn;
    lname = ln;
}

public class Account
{

private Customer cust;
private int accNum = 0;
private double balance;

Account(Customer c)
{
    cust = c;
    balance = 0;
    accNum++;
}

public class DataBase
{

private Account accCust;
int getAcc = 0;

ArrayList<Account> chaseAccts = new ArrayList<>();

public void addAcct(Account me)
{
    accCust = me;
    chaseAccts.add(me);
}

public void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < chaseAccts.size(); i++)
    {

        System.out.println(chaseAccts.get(i).getAccount() + " " + accCust.getAccNum());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait... Print 3 for *each* of their account numbers? Why bother with account numbers then? I thought account numbers should be unique.

Comment: use `sequence` type of column in database.

Comment: Can you post more of the code, like where you're calling the Account constructor and adding it to the list?  From what you have here, it looks like every Account will have the `accNum` of `1` (initialized to 0 and incremented once in the constructor).

Comment: It is printing 3, I want it to print 1, 2, 3, etc for each account. And Braj, we haven't learned about `sequence` and the prof. only wants code he's taught us so far.

Comment: @SierraBravo - are you writing out the value of accCust instead of the elements in the ArrayList?  That would give you the same value each time, since it always points at the most recently added element.

Comment: That's a *huge* security flaw. *Don't* do that.

Comment: okay, I added more, the `getAccount()` method just gets fname, lname, and balance. So i want it to print like John Doe 7. Where 7 is his accNum because that is where he is in the list.

Comment: Well, to generate a sequential number use a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track the assigned account numbers statically, and assign the new account the next number in the series.  Something like

```
public class Account
{

    private static int nextAccoutNumber = 0;

    private Customer cust;
    private double balance;

    Account(Customer c)
    {
       cust = c;
       balance = 0;
       accNum = ++nextAccountNumber;
    }
}
```

You're adding the new account to the list, but you're also storing it in a local variable. Where you're doing this:

```
System.out.println(chaseAccts.get(i).getAccount() + " " + accCust.getAccNum())
```

you are writing out the accNum value of the same accCust each time.  You need to write

```
System.out.println(chaseAccts.get(i).getAccount() + " " + chaseAccts.get(i).getAccNum());
```

And since you're using a list of type `ArrayList<Account>` you could just write the whole loop as:

```
public void display()
{
    for(Account account : chaseAccts) {
        System.out.println(account.getAccount() + " " + account.getAccNum());
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ha! It worked, but I had to change your code from `accCust.get(i).getAcctNum());` to `chaseAccts.get(i).getAcctNum());`

Comment: Ha ha, you're right. I got burned by copy-paste because I was thinking ahead about converting the whole thing to the Generics version of the loop. Fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a static variable

```
private static int accSeq = 0
private Customer cust;
private int accNum = 0;
private double balance;

Account(Customer C) {
    cust = c;
    balance = 0;
    accNum = ++accSeq;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and I'm getting 0 for everyone.